# Map not get updated when Dataset get updated using CartoDB

Tags: carto, csv, infowindow

I created a dataset in CartoDb using a CSV and created  a map . After that i updated one record's latitude and longitude using carto api. On Info window i print lat and long and it shows updated value. But marker shows in prvious lat and long position not in updated lat and long position.

Answer (score 2):

When you import a dataset into CARTO with latitude and longitude columns, CARTO converts these values into a geometry (and assigning this to the `the_geom` column). So, if you change again any latitude/longitude values after importing, you should:

a. Georeference again your dataset from the Editor's UI.

b. Update `the_geom` column using these new values from the SQL console. You can try something like this:

```
UPDATE 
  table
SET 
  the_geom = cdb_latlng(latitude, longitude)
```

*You could use the `WHERE` clause to limit the update to just the values that you have edited.

c. Update `the_geom` via SQL API:

`https://{username}.carto.com/api/v2/sql?q=UPDATE table SET the_geom = cdb_latlng(latitude, longitude)&api_key={api_key}`

After doing any of these options, if you go to your map, the point(s) will be shown on the right (and latest) position.

Comment: thank u ramiroaznar. its help me a alot. I have another doubt . I want to implement search  option in my map. i followed this tutorial http://bl.ocks.org/oriolbx/14786cdd2dca51f4ec9c . But  on loading my map its shows 'Uncaught Error: sql is read-only in NamedMaps' in my console. I changed privacy settings as Public from Link.  But issue exists. On searching i got another issue 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setSQL' of undefined'. How can i implement search in my map?

Comment: Please if you think I have answered your question, mark it as solved. Then, post this new question into a new thread. That's how Stack Exchange works.

Comment: @baijupv please, questions not related with your original topic should be posted separately, otherwise they won't be easily accessible.